# Eclipse PDT run as webpage refuses to work

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse PDT version 1.3.0

PHP Version 5.3.8

Running on windows XP Pro

When I open the pages on localhost they work fine. But the 'Run as webpage' command on Eclipse doesn't work at all. It doesn't even show an error.

The only thing that happens when I start a file is that I get a dialog that says...

'Note that no files will be published to the server' and then gives the path to the server file.

When I press OK, nothing happens.

Help please

Comment: Are you attempting to attach a debugger? If so, do you have a debugger installed? There's native support for XDebug or Zend IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Eclipse and had this problem too. I had to change my workspace path to point to my local server. I still received the "Note..." error, but since the files were already on the local server, I was able to view them without a 404 error.

Hope this helps.
Paul

Comment: This will work (as far as serving pages) but it means you're using your own server process rather than one managed by Eclipse - so no debugging support/similar. That said, if all you want is a page served, it's a quick win. Welcome to SO.